# Kineticjs textpath set text height

Tags: canvas, svg, kineticjs

Is it possible, in a textpath, to set the text height? I want to stretch the text vertically.

```
var text = new Kinetic.TextPath({
    x: 0,
    y: 0,
    fill: '#333',
    fontSize: 24,
    fontFamily: 'Arial',
    text: '123456789',
    data: 'M50,50 C60,0 140,0 150,50'
});
```

According to the [documentation](http://kineticjs.com/docs/Kinetic.TextPath.html), there is a `getTextHeight()` method. But there is no property `textHeight` or a method like `setTextHeight()`.

I would use a normal text object but, unfortunately, i have to curve the text.

[**jsFiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/tMYCx/)

Comment: can you provide a jsFiddle/jsBin/plunkr?

Comment: see modified answer below

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Get text height is just a utility function which sends back a measurement, there is no 'Set' because there is nothing to set as you would be affecting the background styles.

Unfortunately there is no way to "stretch" the text right out of the box, you would have to do some odd workarounds to achieve this. Something like saving the item as an image and stretching the image, but I don't recommend this approach.

Your best bet is to scale the object, http://kineticjs.com/docs/Kinetic.TextPath.html#scaleY

```
myText.scaleY(2);
```

http://jsfiddle.net/tMYCx/1/

Comment: Thanks for pointing out the scale methods. I was hoping there would be another way because this isn't really the result i was looking for. I guess i have to scale every character seperately or something..

Comment: I know, wish me luck ;)

Comment: @RobinvdA - good luck, BTW, what exactly is the case that you need to stretch curved text? there ought to be something else you can do rather than trying a major hack of the API.

Comment: I'm writing an application which virtually prints text on an image (the product). The application should eventually show an image which looks the same as the actual physical product. The text on the product is editable by customers so that's the reason i'm using a library/framework like Kineticjs to be able to change the text. Now, the font i'm using is too small in height, but is correct in width, which means i have to stretch it. Can you think of a possible alternative?

Comment: well, kineticjs is a pretty good library. I can't think of a way around this, scale is pretty much the only way to go, maybe a combination of changing font size, font type, and scale would achieve what you want.

Comment: It sounds like you will be reusing this stretched text often in your app. How about using one of the online font creation tools and create a font from your stretched letters.  This method lets KineticJS do all the difficult positioning/rotating of text along a path.  Best of both worlds!

Comment: @MarkE - can you provide a link to an example?

Comment: Probably, let me google.........OK, this site gives you a Word template that you can put images of your stretched text into letter-by-letter.  Then they create fonts from the templates.  The available formats are:  TrueType, OpenType or SVGFont.  If you can spring for a few bucks I remember the art department of one of my clients saying that High-Logic does a good job of font creation: http://www.high-logic.com/font-editor/fontcreator.html

Comment: @markE Sounds like a nice alternative! I'll look into it